# find a special element in group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $G=\langle x, y, z| xyx^{-1}=zy, xzx^{-1}=z, yz=zy\rangle$, denote $l^1(G)^{\times}$ to be the set of units in $l^1(G)$, which we have considered as a ring with multiplication defined by the usual convolution, i.e., $(\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_gg)(\sum_{h\in G}\mu_hh)=\sum_{g, h\in G}\lambda_g\mu_hgh$.

Can we find $l=p_1(y, z)x^{n_1}+\cdots p_k(y,z)x^{n_k}\in l^1(G)^{\times}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k2^{n_i}p_i(y,z)(1-z^{n_i}y)=0$?

Here, $\forall~ 1\leq i\leq k, ~p_i(y,z)\in \mathbb{Z}G$ and $n_1<\cdots <n_k\in \mathbb{Z}$ to be determined. Note that the group element $x$ does not appear in $p_i(y, z)$.

---

Remarks:

This problem is related to the Ore condition. I want to show that $l$ does not exist, suppose it exists, then I have considered the natural quotient map $\phi: G\to H=G/<z^2>$. Note that it would induce a map $\phi: l^1(G)^{\times}\to l^1(H)^{\times}$, then $\phi(l)\in l^1(H)^{\times}$, but I still could not handle this..

Comment: Can you provide more motivation? What have you tried, etc?

Comment: @ Grumpy, it is related to the Ore condition. I want to show that $l$ does not exist, suppose it exists, then I have considered  the natural quotient map $\phi: G\to H=G/\langle z^2 \rangle$. Note that it would induce a map $\phi: l^1(G)^{\times}\to l^1(H)^{\times}$, then $\phi(l)\in l^1(H)^{\times}$, but I still could not handle this..

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include this?

Comment: @ Grumpy, I have edit it. Hope it help.

Comment: see the element $l$ given here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132311/find-a-special-element-in-group-algebra/135599#135599

Comment: Could anyone suggest a math. Software so that I could do some quick experiment on the same type problems?

Comment: @ougao: Regarding math software, see [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) - it has support for group rings, and there are some packages extending it further, e.g. [LAGUNA](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/laguna.html), [UnitLib](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/unitlib.html), [Wedderga](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/wedderga.html). Of course your mileage may vary dependently on the underlying ring and group.

Comment: @alexander, thanks, I would try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above link in the comment contains a solution by ad hoc method.